# jQuery selectoToUISlider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using this plugin, http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/

What I am trying to achieve is getting the value of the slider in order to change a value in another element in the dom. I've managed to get to the stage whereby if I show the dropdown and then change the dropdown, it will update, however moving the slider doesn't seem to fire the bound change event.

Here is my code to make it a litte clearer hopefully.

http://jsfiddle.net/x3KNb/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/x3KNb/3/

You can take advantage of the sliderOptions option, which allows you to add functions to the slider events ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#events ).

ui.value will return the index of the selected element, from there you can grab the li value with the :nth-child() selector

```
sliderOptions: {
                change: function(e,ui){
                    $('#result .item.'+item+' .price').text(($('#result ul li:nth-child('+ (ui.value + 1) +')').text()));
                }
            }
```